# Single arrow vs double arrow mix and match

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, notation, operands

I frequently see `$var->another_var`, or `$somevar=>yet_another`, or even `$third_var->another=>$fourth_var` in various snippets of code.

Is there some super amazing info-graphic somewhere that clearly explains the various usages and what they mean, specifically within a PHP context?

(In my case, using Drupal, which uses LOTS of arrays, but probably useful in lots of other CMSs / frameworks.)

**EDIT:** I have since been informed about a catch-all page that has a very useful, encyclopedic list of various symbols and syntaxes. However, I believe one section NOT covered there is the mix-and-match combo of $var->element=>$anothervar.

Comment: Original question has been edited to emphasize uniqueness. Please reevaluate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$var->another_var` is "property `another_var` of object referenced by `$var`".
- `$somevar=>yet_another` is used in array definitions, like this: `$arr = array($somevar => yet_another)`. It would define an associative property with key equal to the value of variable `$somevar`, and value equal to the constant `yet_another`.
- `$third_var->another=>$fourth_var` can be rewritten so it becomes more clear:

  ```
  array(  /*key=*/ ($third_var->another)  =>  /*value=*/ $fourth_var  )`
  ```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Single arrow - [T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)**

`->`

This is used for access to an object property and the value associated with that property.

```
$object->property='value'
```

I have a dog and his name is Captain

```
$dog->name='Captain';
```

Now I have access to properties of my dog. The property that we have set is name

```
$dogName=$dog->name;
echo $dogName;
```

Will output: `Captain`

I can also add other properties and their associated value to my object.

```
$dog->weight='57lbs';
```

Now my object has two properties associated with it, name and weight.

**Double arrow - [T_DOUBLE_ARROW](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)**

`=>`

As is stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) an array is just a map of comma separated keys and the values associated with the key. The double arrow is essentially an assignment operator that assigns, or associates, the value to a key.

```
$array = array("key" => "value");
```

Again using the dog example.

```
$dog = array("name" => "Captain", "weight" => "57lbs");
```

And we can access values in my dog array by the respective keys.

```
$fatDog = $dog["weight"];
echo $fatDog;
```

Will output: `57lbs`

**Combinations of single and double arrow**

```
$object->property=>$value;
```

This combines object/property with key/values. If we break it down into it's constituents it can make things much more clear.

We know that `$object->property` will yield the value associated with the property. Lets start by associating that with a variable:

```
$valueAssociatedWithProperty = $object->property;
```

Using substitution into the original gives:

```
$valueAssociatedWithProperty => $value;
```

We have seen that before it is just the key/value of an array! Lets apply this to the dog example and see what comes out:

```
$dog->name="Captain";
$description="He is crazy";
$array = array($dog->name => $description);
// $array = array("Captain" => "He is crazy");
$whatIsCaptain = $array["Captain"];
echo $whatIsCaptain;


He is crazy
```

I hope this helps.

Also look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) for all the references you could ever hope for!